# Can GJK be used with the same "direction finding method" every time?

Tags: collision-detection, algorithm

In my deliberations on GJK (after watching http://mollyrocket.com/849) I came up with the idea that it ins not neccessary to use different methods for getting the new direction in the doSimplex function.

E.g. if the point A is closest to the origin, the video author uses the negative position vector `AO` as the direction in which the next point is searched. If an edge (with A as an endpoint) is closest, he creates a normal vector to this edge, lying in the plane the edge and `AO` form. If a face is the feature closest to the origin, he uses even another method (which I can't recite from memory right now)

However, while thinking about the implementation of GJK in my current came, I noticed that the negative direction vector of the newest simplex point would *always* make a good direction vector.

Of course, the next vertex found by the support function could form a simplex that less likely encases the origin, but I assume it would still work.

Since I'm currently experiencing problems with my (yet unfinished) implementation, I wanted to ask whether this method of forming the direction vector is usable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the negative vector of the most recently added point will *not* always be a good search direction. I can understand if your intuition brought you to this conclusion, but it's wrong.

Search directions are about finding support points that are furthest along a Voronoi region, away from the current simplex. Search directions are not only about vertices. Besides just watching Casey's video you should study GJK more formally to make sure you really understand what is going on.

In the case of Casey's video, he's just trying to find any axis of separation between two convex hulls in order to early out GJK, not even caring to find the distance between the two objects. This is actually not the original GJK algorithm, but a modified one that quickly finds separating axes.

Comment: Actually, I read 2 papers and 3 websites about GJK. And I, too, only want to find seperation. Due to simplification I just cancel the movement if a collision occurrs. But still I thank you for your explanation.